# DDR Data strobe wiring

Tags: ram, ddr

I have a device that has a unified memory architecture and has four 32bit ddr ram chips totaling 128bit and only has a single data strobe for the whole 32bit address bus on each chip not for each byte of each chip.

Looking at all the modern ram it has the data strobe on each chip separated into bytes so four are present on a 32bit chip.

I'm wondering if I can either connect each strobe together to the single strobe pin on the controller or just ignore the other three pins if I was to replace the ram or some other fix as the pins are bidirectional and I don't want to damage anything.

Comment: What is your memory controller?, what did the architecture look like?

Comment: The memory controller needs to understand that the bus is 32 bit wide, because it will need to calibrate the delays according to this.

Comment: The memory controller is the NV2A chip of the original Xbox console.
The memory chip's bus is 32bit wide.

There is additional ram footprints and the data strobes for each bank is parallel but in this case the chips on are enabled by bank select so only one would respond on the bus.
the original chips are Samsung K4D263238F-UC50 and they were typically fitted to graphics cards not system memory., I guess it would of been easier to design a memory controller